# Room android database clearAllTables() with whitelist

Tags: android, android-room

I'd like to clear data from almost all tables.
How to do it without manually writing `"DELETE FROM ..."` for each table.

Method `clearAllTables()` does not provide any options for that.

Comment: This question needs updates in order to be answered well. Provide more details.

Comment: @deadfish what's to add? clearAllTables() doesn't have any parameters and its implementation is "DELETE FROM TableName" written for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider the following demo that could be tailored to suit *(as you mention a Method then Java has been assumed/used)*.

First some @Entity annotated classes ("The Tables"):-

**Table1**

```
@Entity
class Table1 {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id;
    String col1;

    public Table1(){}
    @Ignore
    public Table1(String col1) {
        this.col1=col1;
    }
    @Ignore
    public Table1(Long id, String col1) {
        this.id=id;
        this.col1=col1;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCol1() {
        return col1;
    }

    public void setCol1(String col1) {
        this.col1 = col1;
    }
}
```

and **Table2**

```
@Entity
class Table2 {
   @PrimaryKey
   Long id;
   String col1;

   public Table2(){}
   @Ignore
   public Table2(String col1) {
      this.col1=col1;
   }
   @Ignore
   public Table2(Long id, String col1) {
      this.id=id;
      this.col1=col1;
   }

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getCol1() {
      return col1;
   }

   public void setCol1(String col1) {
      this.col1 = col1;
   }
}
```

A basic @Database annotated class **TheDatabase**:-

```
@Database(entities = {Table1.class,Table2.class},version = TheDatabase.DATABASE_VERSION,exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
    private static TheDatabase instance;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for demo */
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

- nothing special/tricky

An `@Dao` annotated **abstract class** (so methods with bodies can be utilised), name **AllDAOs** (as referenced above in the **TheDatabase** abstract class):-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDAOs {

   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   abstract long insert(Table1 table1);
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   abstract long insert(Table2 table2);
   @Query("DELETE FROM Table1;")
   abstract int clearTable1();
   @Query("DELETE FROM Table2;")
   abstract int clearTable2();
   @Query("SELECT * FROM Table1")
   abstract List<Table1> getAllFromTable1();
   @Query("SELECT * FROM Table2")
   abstract List<Table2> getAllFromTable2();

   @Query("")
   @Transaction
   int clearTables(String[] tablesToClear) {
      int rv = -1;
      int table1RowsDeleted=0;
      int table2RowsDeleted=0;
      for (String s:tablesToClear) {
         if (s.equals("Table1")) {
            table1RowsDeleted = clearTable1();
         }
         if (s.equals("Table2")) {
            table2RowsDeleted = clearTable2();
         }
      }
      if ((table1RowsDeleted + table2RowsDeleted) > 0) rv = 1;
      return rv;
   }
}
```

- note the **`clearTables`** method AND the 2 `@Query` annotated clearTable1 and 2 methods.

  - the specific clear methods will delete all the rows from the respective table *(as opposed to using `@Delete` annotated methods which will delete according to the primary key and thus normally just a single row)*
- the clearTables method takes a String Array of tables to be deleted. **IF** the table matches when looping through the list/array then the respective clearTable? method is called.
- If garbage is passed then it is simply ignored.
- A value of -1 is returned if no tables are cleared otherwise 1 if 1 or more tables are cleared.
- the `Query("")` fools Room into thinking something database wise is being undertaken and thus that it wraps the function within a single transaction.

To demonstrate the above the following activity code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "DBINNFO";
    TheDatabase db;
    AllDAOs dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao=db.getAllDAOs();
        dao.insert(new Table1("T1V1"));
        dao.insert(new Table1("T1V2"));
        dao.insert(new Table2("T2V1"));
        dao.insert(new Table2("T2V2"));
        logAll("_AINS");
        dao.clearTables(new String[]{"ooops"});
        logAll("_OOOPS");
        dao.clearTables(new String[]{"Table2"});
        logAll("_CLRT2");
        dao.clearTables(new String[]{"Table1","Table2","Table99"});
        logAll("_CLR1,2&99");
    }


    void logAll(String tag_suffix) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("DATA EXTRACTED:-");
        for (Table1 t: dao.getAllFromTable1()) {
            sb.append("\n\tTABLE1 COL1 Value is " + t.getCol1());
        }
        for (Table2 t: dao.getAllFromTable2()) {
            sb.append("\n\tTABLE2 COL1 Values is " + t.getCol1());
        }
        Log.d(TAG+tag_suffix,sb.toString());
    }
}
```

When the above is run for a new install the  the log contains:-

```
2024-02-15 13:10:16.547 D/DBINNFO_AINS: DATA EXTRACTED:-
        TABLE1 COL1 Value is T1V1
        TABLE1 COL1 Value is T1V2
        TABLE2 COL1 Values is T2V1
        TABLE2 COL1 Values is T2V2
2024-02-15 13:10:16.552 D/DBINNFO_OOOPS: DATA EXTRACTED:-
        TABLE1 COL1 Value is T1V1
        TABLE1 COL1 Value is T1V2
        TABLE2 COL1 Values is T2V1
        TABLE2 COL1 Values is T2V2
2024-02-15 13:10:16.559 D/DBINNFO_CLRT2: DATA EXTRACTED:-
        TABLE1 COL1 Value is T1V1
        TABLE1 COL1 Value is T1V2
2024-02-15 13:10:16.569 D/DBINNFO_CLR1,2&99: DATA EXTRACTED:-
```

- after the insert **AINS** all four rows (2 per table) exist.
- after the first invocation of the clearTables method, where the non-existant ooops table is attempted to be cleared then all four rows accross both tables exist
- after clearing Table2 then only the 2 rows in Table1 remain
- after clearing Table1, Table2 and Table99 (which does not exist) then no data remains.

***Note***

Although *without writing DELETE FROM ....* was specified. It is STRONGLY suggested that you do in fact write them all, like the demo does.

The alternatives are more complex and/or could be open to issues as typically you would have to avoid Room's testing for valid SQL, perhaps driven by interrogating the schema aka the sqlite_master table (not impossible to do though).

---

**Via `sqlite_master`**

IF you really want to save writing then here is an example that is automatic but can be told to either include or exclude a list of table names (noting that SQLite, Room and Android system tables are excluded in either case).

AS such consider the following method added to the `@Database` annotated class:-

```
public void clearTablesViaSQLiteMaster(String[] tables, boolean clear) {
    SupportSQLiteDatabase sdb = this.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    sdb.beginTransaction();
    Cursor csr = sdb.query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite%' AND name NOT LIKE 'android%' AND name NOT LIKE 'room_master%'");
    while(csr.moveToNext()) {
        if (isTableInList(tables,csr.getString(0)) && clear) {
            sdb.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + csr.getString(0)  + ";");
        }
        if ((!isTableInList(tables,csr.getString(0)) && !clear)) {
            sdb.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + csr.getString(0) + ";");
        }
    }
    sdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sdb.endTransaction();
}

private boolean isTableInList(String[] tables,String table) {
    boolean rv=false;
    for (String t: tables) {
        if (table.toLowerCase().equals(t.toLowerCase())) {
            rv=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

- the `isTableInList` method checks to see if the specified table is in the list of tables, returning true or false.
- the `clearTablesViaSQLite` processes ALL tables as per extracted from the schema i.e. the `sqlite_master` table. See the query that protects system tables.
- depending upon the boolean 'clear' parameter a table will if clear is true) be cleared it is both in the list and the extracted table names; if clear is false then all tables will be cleared unless they are in the list of tables passed.
- ***Note that this alternative has NOT ben extensively tested, it is meant to show the alternative technique***

---

Comment: Thank you very much. I would consider both options, but I wanted to avoid writing a method for 50 tables and remember about it with each new one.